# Storing EJB 3 Session Bean references into Map

Tags: java, jndi, ejb-3.0, stateful-session-bean, session-bean

Currently I am using **`EJB3.0 session beans`** in my application. Normally i lookup the bean using `jndi name` and call the concerned method.  But recently what I was suggested to store these references in a `Map` rather than looking up again and again.

> Is this a good practice to store `Session Bean` references into `Map`
>   to avoid their lookup every time ? Or is it Hazardous ? What kind of
>   problems if at all application may have to encounter ?

If it is a good practice then I have another concern.

> Class that contains `Map` to store references is part of **Module A.** While
>   `session beans` are part of **Module B1 ...Bn**. So Once after looking up when I
>   store the reference in `Map`, I can retrieve it back. In the meantime
>   **Module Bn** is redeployed but A remains as it is. So now after looking up
>   the bean from the Map ( as it contains entry) using it, **`ClassCast Exception`** is thrown.

What is the reason of that and how can I avoid ? 
I am using JBOSS Application server - **jboss 5.1.0.GA**

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to cache references to stateless and singleton session bean lookups.  That's basically what the `@EJB` annotation does when you use it on a field.  (It obviously does not work for stateful session beans, which return a distinct EJB reference for each lookup.)

You didn't mention your application server and didn't provide a stack trace for the ClassCastException, but restarting a module very likely creates a new class loader for the new instance of the application, which means the EJB references that you have cached are now incompatible.  I would have guessed a similar ClassCastException would happen even if you didn't cache the result, but perhaps your application server has a workaround for that.  It's probably best to restart all caller modules (or just the entire application) when restarting EJB modules.

Comment: Yeah, I did not post logs because it happened a long back and since then I am not using caching. So does that mean if I am using **`@EJB`** annotation over my field, Its just redundant to cache these references ? And yes when I don't use cache , after reloading of module fresh loopup of bean works without any problem. Your class loader theory seems convincing but is **`ClassCastException`** most appropriate in these cases. Or may be when reload a module, its pool of references is erased by application server maintained with it and fresh one is created